# CodeIgniter RESTful API Library Response

Tags: php, api, rest, codeigniter-2

This question is related to the CodeIGniter RESTful API library found here. I hope someone here is using this library and can offer some help :) .

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

I have installed this library and set up a working environment with it. I have been able to get data back as well. For use, I have created a very simple class that I am accessing with the following code:

```
<?php

 require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

 class Users extends REST_Controller
 {
      public function list_get()
      {
           $this->load->database();

           $data = $this->db->get('users')->result();

           $this->response($data, 200); 
       }

  }
```

To get at this controller, I have done a call to the following URL:

"http://localhost/mgtapp/index.php/api/users/list/format/json"

While I am getting back data, I see that the header content type is set to text/html instead of json and I am also getting errors in php that say "headers already sent". I have tried to remove the format from the end of the url and send it in via an "accept" but I get the same errors and I see the content type being set as text/html. When I run the example, I see the response coming back as it should (as json in the content type) so I do not understand what I am doing wrong here that the content type is not being set correctly. IF someone can shed some light it would be super helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to take a stab in the dark here but that tutorial is from feb 2010, are you using the same version of codeigniter as he was in that tutorial? Who knows what has changed in 2.5 years!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am answering this question because the reason for my troubles was a stupid one.

I had a couple of lines under the "?>" of my php class controller and apparently that was messing it up. Sorry!

Anybody else with this issue, check that first!